# Elegant way to handle constructor only for testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, constructor

I have a base class which is used by many places:

```
class base {

  base(param1, param2 ...) // constructor 1, which is the legit constructor

  base(param3, param4 ...) // constructor only for unit testing!!!
  base(param5, param6 ...) // constructor only for unit testing!!!
}
```

Is there an elegant way to handle this case? It's really confusing to have some constructors only for testing. I simplify the above case and in reality we have multiple 'real' constructors and many more 'fake' constructors. As time goes by, people started to use fake constructor and it becomes not maintainable... What's a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is advisable. In addition to the problems you've outlined, having a constructor that's strictly for unit testing means you aren't really testing the class as it is going to be used outside of testing, rendering your test results questionable.

Comment: Well, even if this is the case, there's no way for me to change it overnight. What's the best way to handle this? We can start re-factoring but people keep adding real usage using the fake constructors...

Answer (score 0):

What do the fake constructors do that can't be done in your test code instead?

Testing via the public api is generally desirable because this defines the set of behaviors you want to ensure are implemented correctly.

When the code you want to test depends on other, complex objects, you can still use the public api, but with these dependencies mocked out.

See also: https://testing.googleblog.com/2013/03/testing-on-toilet-testing-state-vs.html

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, to avoid more of the additional constructors to be used unintendedly: You could make the constructors that are only intended to be used by testing `private`, and make the test class a `friend`.  This can, certainly, also be used for alternatives to the unusual "constructors for testing" approach: Like, providing private setters for allowing the object state to be altered for testing.

If the reason for having the additional constructors is to simplify the test setup: It may be more elegant to create helper factory functions in your test.  These would create the properly configured instances of `base`.  For example, you could have factory functions like `make_base_that_behaves_like_xxx`, or `make_base_for_xxx`.  The factory functions would then ideally call the "legit" constructor and perform additional adaptations to the object as needed.  This can even lead to a better readable solution than the approach with several specialized constructors.

Note, that the introduction of special constructors can be useful at times to resolve testing problems with legacy code, but not so much as a design pattern for newly created code: Feathers describes it under the name *Parameterize Constructor*.